# sending blank e-mail on contact.php

Tags: php, forms, email

My php form works fine for me but somehow i'm recieving blank emails. I've tried to open the contact.php directly www.domain.com/php/contact.php and it was it. It sent an empty email. Could someone please help me to prevent it?

PHP

```
$mailTo = 'anfrage@domain.de';
$mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
$mailSubject    = 'Kontakt';
$returnPage = 'versand_erfolgreich.php';
$returnErrorPage = 'versand_fehler.php';
$mailText = "";
if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])) {

   foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {

      if(is_array($value)) {

          $mailText .= $name . ":\n";

          foreach($valueArray as $entry) {

             $mailText .= "   " . $value . "\n";
          } // ENDE: foreach
      } // ENDE: if  

      else {

          $mailText .= $name . ": " . $value . "\n";
      } // ENDE: else
   } // ENDE: foreach
} // if

 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

     $mailtext = stripslashes($mailtext);
 }

$mailSent = @mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailText, "From: ".$mailFrom);

if($mailSent == TRUE) {
   header("Location: " . $returnPage);
}
else {
   header("Location: " . $returnErrorPage);
}

exit();
```

HTML

```
        <form class="form1" id="formular" role="form" action="php/kontakt.php" id="subscribeForm" method="POST">


        <input class="inputsolo" type="text" name="Name" id="fname"  placeholder="Name*" required="required">
        <input class="inputsolo" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse*" required="required">
        <input class="inputsolo" type="text" name="Telefon" id="phone" placeholder="0221 111 222*" required="required">
        <input class="inputsolo" type="text" name="Betreff" id="betreff" placeholder="Betreff">
        <input tabindex="-1" class="inputsolo betreff2" type="text" value="1" name="Betreff2" id="betreff2" placeholder="Betreff">
        <input class="inputsolo paket" type="text" name="Ausgewählt:" id="web1" value="Webpaket Basis" readonly><img class="closewahl close1" src="css/images/close.png" alt="close"></img></input>
        <input class="inputsolo paket" type="text" name="Ausgewählt:" id="web2" value="Webpaket Erweitert" readonly><img class="closewahl close2" src="css/images/close.png" alt="close"></img></input>
        <input class="inputsolo paket" type="text" name="Ausgewählt:" id="web3" value="Webpaket Business" readonly><img class="closewahl close3" src="css/images/close.png" alt="close"></img></input>
        <input class="inputsolo paket" type="text" name="Ausgewählt:" id="web4" value="Webpaket Universal" readonly><img class="closewahl close4" src="css/images/close.png" alt="close"></img></input>
        <textarea class="inputpoly" name="message" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht.." id="message"></textarea>

        <p id="fehler400"><u>ACHTUNG:<br>Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.</u><br><small>Verdacht auf Spam-Bot.</small><br>Bitte kontaktieren Sie uns per E-Mail oder telefonisch.<br><font style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;"><a href="tel:+32221212121" style="text-decoration:none;outline:none;color:#008aff;">+32221212121</a></font></p>
            <input class="blue-btn" type="submit" id="send" value="Senden">
        </form>
```

Comment: What is that `$valueArray` on line 5?? shouldn't it be `$value`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add `name="submit_button"` to your submit button

Notice that you send emails even if your $_POST is empty so you shoult put all your code in `if(isset($_POST["submit_button"]))` block

Answer (score 0):

I am not PHP person, but i think condition should be like below:

```
$mailTo = 'anfrage@domain.de';
$mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
$mailSubject    = 'Kontakt';
$returnPage = 'versand_erfolgreich.php';
$returnErrorPage = 'versand_fehler.php';
$mailText = "";
if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])) {

   foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {

      if(is_array($value)) {

          $mailText .= $name . ":\n";

          foreach($valueArray as $entry) {

             $mailText .= "   " . $value . "\n";
          } // ENDE: foreach
      } // ENDE: if  

      else {

          $mailText .= $name . ": " . $value . "\n";
      } // ENDE: else
   } // ENDE: foreach


    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

     $mailtext = stripslashes($mailtext);
 }

$mailSent = @mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailText, "From: ".$mailFrom);

if($mailSent == TRUE) {
   header("Location: " . $returnPage);
}
else {
   header("Location: " . $returnErrorPage);
}


   } // if



exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should include everything inside this if

`if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])) {`

so not to send the email in a simple visit

Answer (score 0):

Your code should check if there is any value in email and it's not blank, and for that, you need to do this

```
`

if(isset($_POST["submit_button"]) && $_POST['email']!='') {
$mailTo = 'anfrage@domain.de';
$mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
$mailSubject    = 'Kontakt';
$returnPage = 'versand_erfolgreich.php';
$returnErrorPage = 'versand_fehler.php';
$mailText = "";
   foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
      if(is_array($value)) {
          $mailText .= $name . ":\n";
          foreach($valueArray as $entry) {
             $mailText .= "   " . $value . "\n";
          } 
      } 
      else {
          $mailText .= $name . ": " . $value . "\n";
      } 
   } 
}else{
  return false;
```

} 
     if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

```
     $mailtext = stripslashes($mailtext);
 }
$mailSent = @mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailText, "From: ".$mailFrom);
if($mailSent == TRUE) {
   header("Location: " . $returnPage);
}
else {
   header("Location: " . $returnErrorPage);
}

exit();
`
```

Try replacing your with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine on rough note, but your mail function is declared outside your postcondition, so when you open up your contact us page it is giving you error, as when you are opening up that page (without submitting form), then your data variables are not set, and by just hitting the page normally you are calling the mail function because that's not wrapped in post check condition, simple fix is

```
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])) {

                $mailTo = 'anfrage@domain.de';
                $mailFrom = $_POST['email'];
                $mailSubject    = 'Kontakt';
                $returnPage = 'versand_erfolgreich.php';
                $returnErrorPage = 'versand_fehler.php';
                $mailText = "";

                foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {

                  if(is_array($value)) {

                      $mailText .= $name . ":\n";

                      foreach($valueArray as $entry) {

                         $mailText .= "   " . $value . "\n";
                      } // ENDE: foreach
                  } // ENDE: if  

                  else {

                      $mailText .= $name . ": " . $value . "\n";
                  } 
               } 

             if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

                 $mailtext = stripslashes($mailtext);
             }

            $mailSent = @mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailText, "From: ".$mailFrom);

            if($mailSent == TRUE) {
               header("Location: " . $returnPage);
            }
            else {
               header("Location: " . $returnErrorPage);
            }
            }
            exit();
            ?>
```

Also, there is not need to declaring these to variables outside post check condition as you will not be needing them probably, so only set them if you are intended to do something with them :)

Also checked that you are missing name attribute for your submit button (which is very critical) and that should be :

```
    <form class="form1" id="formular" role="form" action="php/kontakt.php" id="subscribeForm" method="POST">


    <input class="inputsolo" type="text" name="Name" id="fname"  placeholder="Name*" required="required">
    <input class="inputsolo" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse*" required="required">
    <input class="inputsolo" type="text" name="Telefon" id="phone" placeholder="0221 111 222*" required="required">
    <input class="inputsolo" type="text" name="Betreff" id="betreff" placeholder="Betreff">
    <input tabindex="-1" class="inputsolo betreff2" type="text" value="1" name="Betreff2" id="betreff2" placeholder="Betreff">
    <input class="inputsolo paket" type="text" name="Ausgewählt:" id="web1" value="Webpaket Basis" readonly><img class="closewahl close1" src="css/images/close.png" alt="close"></img></input>
    <input class="inputsolo paket" type="text" name="Ausgewählt:" id="web2" value="Webpaket Erweitert" readonly><img class="closewahl close2" src="css/images/close.png" alt="close"></img></input>
    <input class="inputsolo paket" type="text" name="Ausgewählt:" id="web3" value="Webpaket Business" readonly><img class="closewahl close3" src="css/images/close.png" alt="close"></img></input>
    <input class="inputsolo paket" type="text" name="Ausgewählt:" id="web4" value="Webpaket Universal" readonly><img class="closewahl close4" src="css/images/close.png" alt="close"></img></input>
    <textarea class="inputpoly" name="message" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht.." id="message"></textarea>

    <p id="fehler400"><u>ACHTUNG:<br>Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.</u><br><small>Verdacht auf Spam-Bot.</small><br>Bitte kontaktieren Sie uns per E-Mail oder telefonisch.<br><font style="font-family:arial,sans-serif;"><a href="tel:+32221212121" style="text-decoration:none;outline:none;color:#008aff;">+32221212121</a></font></p>
        <input class="blue-btn" type="submit" id="send" value="Senden" name="submit_button">
    </form>
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I've changed everything you guys suggested me here and it works fine now! :))

Comment: @GAX Glad to know that :) Upvote and Mark correct if this helped you. :)

Comment: I would upvote but i can't. I'm new on stackoverflow :)